# Collapsing hide/show elements problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So, here is my problem: This code doesn't work here, but it does here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6kaV/33/ (I mean after click animations) I would also like to add some text below 80*80 example images, which would move with panel (where I have written Model1 and Model2) after I click to show them. Where am I doing mistake, and how can I put text that would move ? I am sorry for my english and for not knowing all the Javascript things, but I would appreciate some help, thanks.

```js
$(".pane-launcher").click(function () {
 // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';
 
    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'up' };
 
    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;
    $('.pane.active, #'+this.id+'-pane').toggle(effect, options, duration).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.pane-launcher{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    display:block;
}
#rules {
    left:0px;
}
#scenarios {
    left:90px;
}
.pane{
    position:absolute;    
    left: 0;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
    opacity:1;
}
#rules-pane {
    top:80px;
    width:170px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#scenarios-pane {
    top:80px;
    width:170px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rules" class="pane-launcher"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
<div id="rules-pane" class="pane">Model1</div>
<div id="scenarios" class="pane-launcher"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></div>
<div id="scenarios-pane" class="pane">Model2<br><img src="http://placehold.it/170x20"></div>

<div>
<p>
TEXT BELOW
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Lukas.. looking at the snippet, it looks as though it's working at the moment, so I assume I'm misreading the question. Do you mind clarifying the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs It works for me only in external Link ( http://jsfiddle.net/e6kaV/33/ ), but it throws some errors at me at this page. Here I can expand each box once, but I wont collapse again after clicking on 80*80 box. Animation also doesnt work here. I know it works at jsfiddle, but i wonder why it doesnt work here. I also asked about some text, that would come after 80*80, that would move after some box IS expanded. Dorty for my english again

Comment: If it works in jsfiddle then you know the code works overall, so let's focus on the text issue. Can you please expand more on the issue you're having with text after the box? I'm still not 100% what you're after.

Comment: @JohnDetlefs sorry for delay, had to do some images. This is how  it looks like when i add some text after these ,,boxes,, in HTML https://postimg.org/image/7shx9z0bl/aa326f18/. You can see the text below grey 80*80 images. But I want to have it like this: https://postimg.org/image/43jxevu4x/ ( ,,Random text,, was added in painting.

Comment: Amd then, when new boxes are shown, i want the text to move Down like this: https://postimg.org/image/tkikt83gx/ sorry for nad explaining